# Specify Hex Color Value in Android Metadata

Tags: android, metadata

I am working on getting some meta-data working on Android. Most specifically, I am getting application-level meta-data to set a View's background in the following formats:

```
<meta-data android:name="background"
           android:value="red" />

<meta-data android:name="background"
           android:resource="@drawable/my_red_background" />

<meta-data android:name="background"
           android:value="#FF0000" />
```

I am using the following code to parse the information:

```
ApplicationInfo app = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
Bundle metaData = app.metaData;
if (metaData != null) {
    int resourceID = metaData.getInt("background", -1);
    if (resourceID != -1) {
        //set the background resource of my view (THIS WORKS)
    }
    else {
        String background = metaData.getString("background");
        if (background != null) {
        try {
            backgroundColor = Color.parseColor(background);
            //Set background color (THIS WORKS for 'red', 'blue', etc.)
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

If I use the resource method and point it at a drawable, this works. If I use a color string like "red", "blue", "yellow", etc - these also work. However, if I attempt to use a color in any of the formats preceded by a hashmark (#FF0000, #FFFF0000, etc), this does not work, even though the [Android Documentation](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html) suggests that it should:

[image: android:value description]

Is this a known bug? Is there a simple workaround (other than just using a simple string or a drawable reference)? Or am I missing something? I am using a Asus Transformer Prime 10.1 TF301 Tablet to test (Android 4.0.3).

**EDIT**

I wanted to note that this is not a problem with `Color.parseColor()`. Android never enters the statement `if (background != null)`, so somehow the meta data is not getting recognized as a String at all.

Comment: Looking at the docs and the implementation, it does look as though `parseColor` should work. It also doesn't seem to have changed since 2.3.7 at least. Weird. Here's [the implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/graphics/Color.java#Color.parseColor%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: @dmon, I added an edit to my post to note that it is not a problem with `parseColor`, but rather that Android does not correctly parse the manifest xml, or does not recognize the hex color as a string.

Comment: Yep, saw it. I also saw you figured it out :)

Comment: Slight aside that I think contributed to the confusion: metaData.getInt() does not return the resource ID for "background". It returns the value for "background". See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getInt(java.lang.String, int)

Comment: @BrianAttwell, Check out the docs here: http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element.html The resource ID stuff all works great, but as of writing this question, I had been expecting the String value "#FF0000" would work, but have since discovered that an escape character is required.

Comment: "The ID of the resource is the value assigned to the item". What I should have said was: resourceId just means backgroundValue.

Comment: When I tested your code, I noticed that metaData.getInt("background", -1) was returning #FF0000. This is what made me realize your string represented an integer. (Although it looks like you may have already figured it out at that point)

Comment: Yeah, that occurs since I am using the background variable for either a resource or a color. It's unfortunate Android prints that - but it works out for me either way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved! This is not an Android bug, per-se, but rather an Android documentation bug (*Surprise, surprise!*). A hex color needs an escape character for it to be handled correctly:

```
<meta-data android:name="background"
           android:value="\#FF0000" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1)** Use a backslash so that value is a string instead of a number.

**Solution 2)** Instead of calling `Color.parseColor(bundle.parseString(..))`, just use getInt(..) without a backslash.

**Background:**

`android:value="#aabbgg"` is a number

`android:value="\#aabbgg"` is a string